# PHP fopen function only works one way

Tags: php

Ok let me explain what's goin one:

I have 2 hosts/websites, **Host A** and **Host B**. When i'm using the php function `fopen` code on **Host A** to **Host B** it works, i can read the title of the page. BUT when i go from **Host B** to **Host A** it won't work. **And now the strange thing** when i go from **Host B** to **example.com**. It does work??

I think that it's a wrong setting on **Host A** but, i can't change that much on the server. Does somebody know how to fix the problem? So i can go from **Host B** and read the title of a file on **Host A**?

---

Code that i use to open a file (and is hosted on **Host B**) and search the title:

```
$file = fopen ("http://promike360.esy.es/main_site/", "r"); //This is HOST A
if ($file) {
    echo "<p>Loadig remote file succesfull.</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>Unable to open remote file.</p>";
    exit;
}
while (!feof ($file)) {
    $line = fgets ($file, 1024);

    /* This only works if the title and its tags are on one line */
    if (preg_match ("@\<title\>(.*)\</title\>@i", $line, $out)) {
        $title = $out[1];
        echo $title;
        break;
    }
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: I think u need to have read permission on Host A. check the file permission using ls -ltr and then chmod -R 755 foldername

Comment: @vSugumar if i go to http://promike360.esy.es/main_site/ i can see the page, and i can edit the page in a editor using ftp. Or has that nothing todo with the persmission?

Comment: I just checked your code works I am able read the content.

Comment: @vSugumar wait.. whut? you see a white page with the text 'ProMike360'? When i run that code on **Host B** (that is http://counselinginnerlijkekompas.nl/index1.php ) the page will keep loading and loading and loading. And then at the end it says 'Unable to open remote file.' Why is **Host B**  able to open example.com / google.com etc. but not **Host A**

Comment: It works fine on my host too. I put that code in a test php page, and see `Loadig remote file succesfull. ProMike360` when I view it...

Comment: If you turn error reporting on, does it display any errors on your Host B site?  `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 32759);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I fixed it!

After a long time, i came with a solution for my problem.

### But first, the problem

I have 2 hosts, **Host A** and **Host B**. I wanted to read a file on **Host A** by using a script (that is written in PHP and is using the `fopen` function) on **Host B**.
This did not work. What did work, was reading a file that is hosted on **Host B** and read it by the script on **Host A**.  (And no, the file-permissions was configured in the right way).
This is realy strange, and even at this moment i'm writing this. I still don't know how to solve it.

### The solution

The solution to solve this problem, is using jQuery to request the file on **Host A** and add 1 row of php code to the file on **Host A**.


[PHP] The code on **Host A** what needs to be inside the php file.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

This says to your browser that you can go to this host. Otherwise the browser will block your request (This is what someone told me).


[jQuery/Javascript] The code that i used to read the file

```
$.get("http://example.com/file.php", function( data ) {

});
```